# Linux implementation - TCP RTO calculation

Tags: c, linux, tcp, linux-kernel, kernel

While reading the book "TCP/IP illustrated Volume 1" by Richard Stevens I ran into the information that there was a improvement in TCP regarding the calculation of RTO.

The book states there are some possible problems in the standard approach because it uses a heavy weight given to the *rttvar* term. This can cause RTO to increase even if the RTT is decreasing.

It later states that linux handles the case where the RTT is decreasing by giving it less weight to the new sample if it's below the "lower end" of the estimated RTT range (*srtt - mdev*) and provides the code snip:

```
if(m < (srtt - mdev))
    mdev = (31/32) * mdev + (1/32) * |srtt - m|
else
    mdev = (3/4) * mdev + (1/4) * |srtt - m|
```

Where:
srtt = smooth round trip time, mdev = deviations of the new measurement vs srtt, and m = new rtt measurement.

My problem is that I can't find this improvement in any linux distribution source code. The function **static void tcp_rtt_estimator(struct sock *sk, long mrtt_us)** inside linux's **tcp_input.c** file work's as described in RFC 6298, but I can't find the improvement mentioned in Steven's book.

My question is was this improvement not implemented due to the unlikeliness of this problem accuring, or maybe was implemented in some versions but removed after testing and getting unsatisfying results, or something else?

I've also come apon the information that there was a Technical conference in 2002 that addressed this improvement. (Proceedings of the FREENIX Track: 2002 USENIX Annual Technical Conference), but couldn't find what their conclusion was.

If anyone has any information on the topic, I'd be very thankful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that RFC 6298 did not make it in Richard Stevens's book in the second edition (Nov 2011), published originally in 1994.
RFC 6298 was published in June 2011.